# RevMob Ads in swift application

Tags: swift, xcode6, revmob, revmobads

Does anyone know what the import statement should be for the RevMobAds framework in swift? I've imported the framework itself which is called RevMobAds.framework but in my AppDelegate.swift file simply saying "import RevMobAds" doesn't work like it would for non third-party frameworks. All the tutorials online are for objective-c projects so I can't really find anything to help. Has anyone had any experience with RevMobAds in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rev Mob has since added a swift implementation guide to its website. To import objective c frameworks, one must use a bridging header